# WPF Telerik RadMenuItem Not Firing On HotKey

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

The snippet below is from a production machine shop application which has a rather utilitarian menu.... I've been asked to add hot keys to some of the menu items; for example, one of the menu items (as seen in the code below) I need to add the F6 key as a hotkey (note the idendical Command for clicking vs hotkey)...   clicking on it works as desired, but the hotkey has seemingly no effect whatsoever (nothing happens).

What am I missing, or otherwise doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    <telerik:RadMenuItem Name="ToolsMenu" Header="Tools">
        <telerik:RadMenuItem Name="ToolsUseFinishLocationMenuItem" Header="Use Finish Location For Bin" Command="{Binding ToolsUseFinishLocationForBinCommand}" InputGestureText="F6">
            <telerik:RadMenuItem.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="F6" Command="{Binding ToolsUseFinishLocationForBinCommand}" />
            </telerik:RadMenuItem.InputBindings>
        </telerik:RadMenuItem>
    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you haven't the keyboard focus on the element. You could think about bind the input to parent element like

```
<Window>
    <Window.InputBinding>
        <KeyBinding ...>
    </Window.InputBinding
    <your element/>
</Window>
```

But maybe problem is somewhere else. You could also use class InputManager, to create hotkeys for whole app.

Put those lines to constructor:

```
InputManager.Current.PostNotifyInput -= PostNotifyInputHandler;
InputManager.Current.PostNotifyInput += PostNotifyInputHandler;
```

And made the method like this:

```
private void PostNotifyInputHandler(object sender, NotifyInputEventArgs args)
    {
        var keyboardArgs = args?.StagingItem?.Input as KeyboardEventArgs;

        var isSecondEvent = keyboardArgs?.RoutedEvent != Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent;
        var performedOnTextBox = keyboardArgs?.OriginalSource is System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

        if (isSecondEvent || performedOnTextBox)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch ((keyboardArgs as KeyEventArgs)?.Key)
        {
            case Key.F6:
                // your command here
                break;
        }
     }
```